# Uploading a csv file with solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

How do I upload a csv file using solrnet ? .

> var solrInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance>();

```
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Desktop\abcd.csv"))
        {
            var response =
               solrInstance.Extract(
                  new ExtractParameters(fileStream, "doc1")
                  {
                      ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                      ExtractOnly = false,

                  });
        }

        solrInstance.Commit();
```

My upload loads as a document instead of parsing each line in csv as my "SolrDocument" type.

Comment: That's not what the Extract feature is for: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

Comment: You could use ISolrConnection.PostStream, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV for parameters.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I am using ISolrConnection.Poststream to upload documents but to commit them I have to add commit=true which causes too many commits error on solr. Is there a way to commit at the end when all the files are uploaded.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">503</int><int name="QTime">844</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Error opening new searcher. exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=4, try again later.</str><int name="code">503</int></lst>
</response>

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar post to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet